# How to get methods with "Priority" attribute value

Tags: c#

I have many methods with different "Priority" attributes such as:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [Priority(2)]
    public void TestCase1()
    {
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [Priority(1)]
    public void TestCase2()
    {
    }
```

I'm able to get all of them but I don't know how to show their priority values

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"a.dll");

var testClasses = assembly.GetTypes().Where(c => c.GetCustomAttribute<TestClassAttribute>() != null);

foreach (var testClass in testClasses)
{
    using (var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\TestsList.txt", true))
    {
         file.WriteLine(testClass);
     }
     var testMethods = testClass.GetMethods().Where(m => m.GetCustomAttribute<TestMethodAttribute>() != null);
     foreach (var testMethod in testMethods)
     {
         using (var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\TestsList.txt", true))
         {
              file.WriteLine(testMethod);
         }
     }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like

```
testMethod.getPriority()
```

Comment: In your loop, get the attributes of `testMethod` (see duplicate) and access the [`PriorityAttribute.Priority`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.priorityattribute.aspx) property.

Comment: I tried this but it couldnt get the priority attribute:

var pAttr = (PriorityAttribute)method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PriorityAttribute), true)[0];

Comment: Then please update your question with that code and what it does and doesn't do, @mention me and I can reopen your question.

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks for pointing me to that link, it is working now. Problem was that the dll being read is outdated hence I wasnt able to get the newly added added attribute in the code, which is the Priority.